# java8 stream style to convert a key-value list to a map?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert a list like [k1, v1, k2, v2] to a map like {k1: v1, k2: v2}. The original code is:

```
List<Object> params = Arrays.asList("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < params.size(); i+=2) {
    String key = (String)params.get(i);
    Object value = params.get(i + 1);
    map.put(key, value);
}
System.out.println(map); // => {k1=v1, k2=v2}
```

Then I want to transform it to java8 stream style? How?

Comment: what's the purpose of this transformation?

Comment: just for study. @AndrewTobilko

Comment: There are some libraries which would make this much easier, such as [StreamEx](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#ofPairs-java.util.List-)

Comment: @PatrickParker, StreamEx solution would be a little better indeed: `IntStreamEx.range(0, params.size(), 2).mapToEntry(i -> (String)params.get(i), i -> params.get(i+1)).toMap();`. Though even having StreamEx in the project I'd probably leave the plain old loop here...

Comment: @PatrickParker, `EntryStream.ofPairs` does different thing: it creates all possible pairs. Here you'll end up with `k1=>v1`, `k1=>k2`, `k1=>v2`, `v1=>k2`, `v1=>v2`, `k2=>v2`.

Comment: @Tagir - ah you mean there's no way to partition based on (stream index % 2)? I wonder if it could be done with a jOOλ window?

Comment: @PatrickParker, of course there is a way: [StreamEx.ofSubLists](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#ofSubLists-java.util.List-int-). If you like it, go ahead: `StreamEx.ofSubLists(params, 2).toMap(list -> (String)list.get(0), list -> list.get(1))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like the tool *StreamEx*

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, but frankly, your for loop is much more readable. I would try to avoid producing such a list in the first place, and have a `List<SomePair>` instead, where `SomePair` contains the key and the value.

```
    List<Object> params = Arrays.asList("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
    Map<String, Object> map =
        IntStream.range(0, params.size() / 2)
                 .collect(HashMap::new,
                          (m, i) -> m.put((String) params.get(i * 2), params.get(i * 2 + 1)),
                          HashMap::putAll);

    System.out.println(map); // => {k1=v1, k2=v2}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Collectors.toMap` if you pipe through `boxed` first: `.boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> (String) params.get(i * 2), i -> params.get(i * 2 + 1)))`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to using `Stream`, you could just use a good-old `Iterator` and call `next` to get the next element. Of course, this will fail if the list does not have an even number of elements.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<Object> iter = params.iterator();
iter.forEachRemaining(x -> map.put((String) x, iter.next()));
```